# Change Tomcat port in GeoServer Docker container

Tags: geoserver, docker

Using GeoServer Docker from https://github.com/geoserver/docker I am unable to change the port of the Tomcat container. As I did not find a server.xml, I tried to set this via the environment variable `CATALINA_OPTS` and the value `-Dcatalina.http.port=8081` as suggested [here](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-catalina_opts-vs-java_opts#use-of-catalinaopts), but Tomcat is still started on default port 8080. After solving this I would also provide a PR to add this to the docs.

Edit: To add context, I am building up a custom docker-compose.yml file that defines another service running on port 8080, so I need the port changed on container (and container network) level. The services are reverse-proxied on the host machine using Traefik running on host port 80.

Comment: Have you tried to edit the ports in `docker run -it -p 80:8080`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62125794/docker-run-p-what-are-this-two-port-numbers-and-what-they-represents?

Comment: Thanks for the question, I edited for more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resorted to COPY a custom server.xml which looks at `${port.http}` into the container. I got the idea from https://github.com/geoserver/docker/pull/39.